# Touch more one button at once

Tags: android

Hello i make appliction like Drum Studio. I need make support for touch more one button at once. For example: User touch button1(AND HOLD IT!) it play sound, but user still hold its, user click another button and it play sound too. How make it programmatically? By default onTouch or onClick use, if 1 button pressed, another buttons not react before button isn't released.

Answer (score 3):

Use the onKeyDown() events to trigger each response and onKeyUp() events to finish them.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html

For touchs, you can use the OnTouchListener

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html

and determine the kind of touch by the MotionEvent:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

To clarify my response: To make a sound while holding one button, you can start the sound when the `ACTION_DOWN` action in the `MotionEvent` event is triggered and stop it with the `ACTION_UP` action of the same event.

- Create a class extending View where you're holding all your buttons.
- Override the onTouchEvent vor that class.
- Switch between the different actions.
- Use event.getX() and event.getY() to figure out where the touch event was originated.
- Check which button is located at that position
- Play the sound accordingly.

Comment: No, sorry, you don't understand the question. I need response next  clicks(touches) after hold(touch) one or more button.

Comment: I think I did understand it. And thats why the link to the MotionEvent page. When the gesture starts it fires the ACTION_DOWN event: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN Once that's fired, you can listen to any other events on the same button or other.

Comment: Check which button is located at that position how?

Comment: OK. That bullet list is exactly what I was talking about. I believe your scenario involves a ViewGroup instead of a View, in which case you have access to all the child Views and can query their positions and compare them to the touch coordinates.

Comment: Indeed I need to improve the way I express myself. I was thinking on detecting the event in the container view, not a transparent image, but you're right, as expressed that comment is wrong.

Comment: Extending class - This enough? 

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class DrumBtn extends View
{
    public DrumBtn(Context context) 
    {
  super(context);
 }

}

Comment: @android_dev use bt.getLeft() , bt.getRight() , etc.

Comment: @LeffelMania should I make it wiki? Feel free to edit it as you see fit. I'm excercising theory here since I'm not even close to an android sdk right now.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot touch two separate Views at the same time, even if multi-touch is supported on your device. If you touch Button1 first, all subsequent MotionEvents (including ones with separate pointer IDs) are bound to that View.

Unless you're using a dedicated game engine like AndEngine that has this sort of functionality built in, your only option is to capture all the MotionEvents yourself (most easily with an empty ImageView covering your entire screen) and route them to the appropriate Views based on their screen coordinates. This can get tricky, especially with multiple touch pointers, but the Android UI framework does not natively support the kind of multi-touch you require.

Comment: I found some apps on market. here buttons work as i need. Look 
    https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bti.myDrums&feature=search_result
    https://market.android.com/details?id=com.phellax.drum&feature=search_result

Comment: I keep updating the answer to make it more clear. The idea is to handle the events from a single View and execute the commands based on the position of the event origin.

Comment: I understand how you need your buttons to work. My explanation of how to make them work that way still stands.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to be using Android 2.0 or higher - previous versions don't support multitouch.

Check the pid in your onTouch - 0 is a single touch, 1 is the second.

Comment: I can find one on Google pretty quick. ;)  This example is actually from a book I got to borrow for a little while.  http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763

Comment: that link shows an example of the event I'm describing above. But from what I understand of the question, the two touch events would be triggered on different buttons, not the same one.